# Is there an easier way to show an alert dialog with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm using ASP.NET and C# to create a form.  When the user clicks submit, I validate the inputs and continue.  If for any reason the inputs are not valid, I show an alert notifying the user of the issues.  If everything checks out, I do my work with the given input.  My problem here is that when I click the submit button, the page refreshes, erasing all input.  Here's an example on what I'm doing in the code behind:

```
saveButton.Click += (s, e) => {
    var errors = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(myField.Text)) errors += "myField is empty or consists of only whitespace.\n";
    //do this for each field
    if (errors == "") { //no errors found!
        //use the input
    }
    else { //something's invalid
        //alert the user
        ShowMessage("Please review these problems before continuing:\n\n" + errors);
    }
};
```

No exceptions are thrown, but if a purposely send invalid input, the page refreshes before it can display the popup.  Here's what I've tried for `ShowMessage()`:

```
private void ShowMessage(string msg) {
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), "alert(\'" + message + "\');", true);
}
```

and

```
private void ShowMessage(string msg) {
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert(\"" + message + "\");</script>");
}
```

Again, each one refreshes the page before the message is shown!
Is there an easier way to show a message dialog without refreshing the page?

Comment: You should use client side validation, for example by using jquery. This will result in a much better user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to validate the inputs and then show a popup if anything is invalid. Like this you won't have to do a postback, which provides a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), title,
         "alert('" + somemessage + "');", true);
```

or like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"redirect",
"alert('message'); window.location='" + 
Request.ApplicationPath + "yourPage.aspx';",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include this C# code in the on button click hundler :

```
MessageBox.Show("Wrong input.", " Error :", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
```

And you can close the first window by adding :

```
Close();
```

Comment: This requires to add Windows Forms dll's into the project and that is a really bad practice in web applications.

Comment: Bad practice? Yeah, showing the popup on the web server instead does sounds like bad practice :-)

Comment: Yes sorry, I skipped *ASP.NET* because i'm a beginner, not like in desktop applications.